# How do I filter out a value from a Vector's object?

Tags: java, vector

I have a `Vector` which contains the following at index 0:

```
[0010004008, 000020, P, false, false]
```

I want to get the value of the first element in it.

In this case I want `0010004008`.

So far I have used:

```
Vector aT = cp.getPlan(wc, prd, "Week", anArray);
aT.elementAt(0);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with using the code provided? Also note that ["The `Vector.elementAt(int)` method is identical in functionality to the `Vector.get(int)` method"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt(int)).

Comment: Cause it returns the entire row as shown above. i only want a specific element of the row m8.

Comment: What data type is the first element? To allow people to understand better, it always helps to provide a [self-contained](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) example.

Comment: all of them are strings..

Comment: Is the first element of `aT` a vector of strings (`["0010004008", "000020", "P", "false", "false"]` or is it a string (`"[0010004008, 000020, P, false, false]"`)?

Comment: ya its like the first on ["0010004008", "000020", "P", "false", "false"]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32879/discussion-between-kasanova-and-dukeling)

Answer (score 0):

[Vector.get(0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29) should work.

```
int value = (Integer) aT.get(0);
```

Comment: this does return the row of object at index 0 but not the individual component or column  value of each individual object.

Comment: Ara you using `java.util.Vector` if yes.. what object you have stored there?

Comment: yes i am. [0010004008, 000020, P, false, false] those are the values returned from index 0. and what it stands for is say, [A,B,C,D,E].. what i am looking for is to get each of these values separately now.. for example i need say C.. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Vector<Vector<String>>` you can call `get(index)` again on the result of your first `get()` call.

```
Vector aT = cp.getPlan(wc, prd, "Week", anArray);
aT.get(0).get(0); // returns "0010004008"
aT.get(0).get(1); // returns "000020"
aT.get(0).get(4); // returns "false"
```